# Rolling (rotate and translate) a 2D circle in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, variable-assignment

Could you please write a MATLAB Script to animate the motion of the rolling disk for two complete rotations, also showing (as a trace) the trajectory of the point on the rim. Take: radius of the disk equal to 10 units, radius of the point is also equal to 10 units.
Produce a static plot for your system, showing the speed of the rim point using the “quiver”
command.

Here is the code so far:

```
figure; 
%XX=[0 2 4 5 0];
%YY=[1 0 1 5 1];
NN=100;
RR=2;
th=linspace(0,360,NN+1)*pi/180;
XX=RRcos(th);
YY=RRsin(th);

h=patch('XData',XX,... 'YData',YY,'FaceColor',[1 0 0]);
axis([0 10 -2 8]);
axis square
N=100; dX=5/N;
for ii=1:N XX=XX+dX;
    set(h,'XData',XX); 
    drawnow; 
    pause(0.1)
end
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. We're happy to help with specific programming problems you're running into but we aren't here to write your code for you. Try writing out the necessary equations and attempting the code yourself first.

Comment: figure;
%XX=[0 2 4 5 0];
%YY=[1 0 1 5 1];
NN=100;
RR=2;
th=linspace(0,360,NN+1)*pi/180;
XX=RR*cos(th); YY=RR*sin(th);

h=patch('XData',XX,...
        'YData',YY,'FaceColor',[1 0 0]);
    axis([0 10 -2 8]);
    axis square
   
N=100;
dX=5/N;
for ii=1:N
    XX=XX+dX;
    set(h,'XData',XX);
    drawnow;
    pause(0.1)
end

Answer (score 0):

just add one timer and then inside the timer function  change the position of circle according the rotation and transform ( if you don't know how to change position then go through with basic geometry concept).